# Public reference to an object

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following outline of code:

```
class B {
    int a = 0;
    void method1() {
        // code
        a = a + 1;
    }
}

public class A extends Thread {

    static B obj1;

    public void run(){
       obj1.method1();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        obj1 = new B();
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.start();
        A a2 = new A();
        a2.start();      
    }
}
```

Now, since `a1` and `a2` are two different objects, shouldn't the value be 1 while printing the value of a?
What am I missing?
How is the global reference for B working? I'm a little confused.

Comment: This snippet doesn't compile, because `obj1` is a non-static reference in a static context. If you fix it to read `B obj1 = new B();`, it will just fail with a `NullPointerException`. Can you please [edit] your question and include a [mcve]?

Comment: You mentioned "while printing the value of a," but I don't see any point in your code where anything is printed.

Comment: Yes @Mureinik! That's why I had pointed out as outline of the code.Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: *shouldn't the value be 1* Does `a = a + 1;` even pretend to appear to be multithread-safe?

Comment: "since a1 and a2 are two different objects, shouldn't the value be 1 while printing the value of a?"  There is only one `B` object created, and it's assigned to the static variable `obj1`.  Therefore `A.obj1.a` is incremented twice -- once when `a1.run()` executes, and once when `a2.run()` executes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't even get this code. You define `run()` but invoke `start()`? And why is `method1()` even there? You need to edit the code and fix some things.

Comment: @cst1992 OP defines `run()` but invokes `start()` because class A inherits from `Thread`.

Comment: @cst1992 if you knew multithreading in java, you wouldn't have got this doubt
start() automatically invokes run(). If you invoke run() directly it would work in a sequential manner making the use of threads useless

Answer (score 0):

This code should produce compilation error.

> How is the global reference for B working?

It doesn't. obj1 (type class B) is a non-static member of class A. The main method is static and not really running in context of any class A object. For this reason, the main function (static function) cannot access obj1 directly.

```java
obj1 = new B();
```

In the above line, there is no actual memory of obj1 to store the reference created by `new B()`. Two different memory for obj1 are created as part of a1 and a2, which need to accessed as a1.obj1 and a2.obj2. Thus, no kind of global reference is created.

What you might be trying to do can be achieved by making obj1 as static.

```java
static B obj1;
```

This can make obj1 act as a global reference as its memory is not part of any class A object. This will make both threads update same variable making value of obj1.a as 2 (not necessarily as the code isn't thread-safe).

Comment: Thanks @RamKumar I was little confused between effects of public and static variables

Comment: @jason44107 a1 is not related to obj1 in any way. They are objects of 2 different classes.